# Altering an array from a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++ (the usual intro for every newbie XD) and I found this unexpected behavior. I traced the variables and arrays in my program until I determined this pattern:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void showArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
void someFunction(int x[], int n) // changes the original values
{
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[2] = 0;
} 
void someFunction2(int * x, int n)
{
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[2] = 0;
} // changes the original values
int someFunction3(int x[], int n)
{
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[2] = 0;
    return 0;
} // changes the original values
int someFunction4(int x[], int n)
{
    x = new int[n];
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[2] = 0;
    return 0;
} // does NOT change the original value

int main(void)
{
    int * y = new int[3];
    y[0] = 0;
    y[1] = 1;
    y[2] = 2;
    showArray(y, 3);
    someFunction4(y, 3);
    showArray(y, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't `someFunction4()` change the array `y` in `main()`? When I call the other `someFunctionX()` in `main()` instead, `y` successfully changes from `{0, 1, 2}` to `{2, 1, 0}`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `someFunction4`, you assign `x` to point to a `new` array of integers, which you then assign. The array pointed to by the variable you passed into the function still points to the old array. The old array stays unchanged, since within `someFunction4` you've set `x` to reference a different array, namely the one you created in your function via `new`.

In order to make the original `x` in `someFunction4()` hold the values you assigned, do one of two things:

1) Get rid of `x = new int[n];`. This will make `someFunction4()` work like the previous ones.

2) Pass a pointer to `x` as an argument to `someFunction4()` and have `someFunction4()` take a pointer.

```
int someFunction4(int *x[], int n)
{
    *x = new int[n];
    (*x)[0] = 2;
    (*x)[1] = 1;
    (*x)[2] = 0;
    return 0;
} // Makes x point to a new a new array
```

And in your main, do

```
someFunction4(&y,3);
```

Comment: thanks. Your answer is clear. So, how to make the old array takes the new value?

Comment: Get rid of the assignment `x = new int[n];`

Comment: what if I want to alter the array size from within the function?

Comment: Have `someFunction4` take a pointer to an int array instead of the int array, then dereference it within your function. That'll change it.

Comment: nope!! obviously, you haven't run the edited code!!
There's an error!!

Comment: Ah, yes, it works now and does what you want. And I have compiled it. Operator precedence, *sigh*.

Answer (score 6):

In each of `someFunction`, `someFunction2`, and `someFunction3`, you are actually passing a [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29) to the memory you allocated for your array in `main()`.  This means that when you operate on the data this pointer points to:

```
x[1] = 1;
```

It actually affects the same memory that `y` points to back in `main()`!

However, in `someFunction4`, you *reassign* the pointer `x` to point to new memory with the statement:

```
x = new int[n];
```

So it no longer points to the same memory that `y` does in `main()`, and any changes you make to it after that (but only within the scope of `someFunction4`!) will not affect `y`.

Answer (score 2):

I made a testcase.

http://ideone.com/fyl6MX

result

```
0 1 2 
0x943b008
0x943b018
0x943b008
0 1 2
```

Second one is the address is a address of new table. As you can see your pointer is locally pointing to other address.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void showArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
void someFunction(int x[], int n) // changes the original values
{
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[2] = 0;
} 
void someFunction2(int * x, int n)
{
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[2] = 0;
} // changes the original values
int someFunction3(int x[], int n)
{
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[2] = 0;
    return 0;
} // changes the original values
int someFunction4(int x[], int n)
{
    x = new int[n];
    std::cout << x << endl;
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 1;
    x[2] = 0;
    return 0;
} // does NOT change the original value

int main(void)
{
    int * y = new int[3];
    y[0] = 0;
    y[1] = 1;
    y[2] = 2;
    showArray(y, 3);

    std::cout << y  << endl;

    someFunction4(y, 3) ;
    std::cout << y << endl;

    showArray(y, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so how to change the original pointing value from within a function?

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how arguments are passed to functions

When you call SomeFunctionN(y,3) then inside SomeFunctionN the 'x' variable is a local variable initialized to point at the same array that y was pointing at in main.

in SomeFunc4 you then create a new array and change you local pointer (x) to point at the new array. All changes you make hit the new array

In all other cases you leave x alone